# android: Web Console(24359): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:334

Tags: android, webview

I use webview replace with a listview. now I can get the first page html by webview, when the page is large than one page, I need show "next page" in the bottom of webview, I use a javascript to handle this as follows:

```
<div id="nextpagebox"></div>
<div id="nextpagebtnbox" style="display:none;">
<p id="nextpagebtn" class="nextpagebtn_untouch"ontouchstart="javascript:this.className='nextpagebtn_touch';"ontouchend="javascript:this.className='nextpagebtn_untouch'"onclick="jsinterface.nextPage();">next page</p><p id="nextpagebtn_isrunning" class="nextpagebtn_untouch" style="display:none;">loading...</p></div><script>type="text/javascript">jsinterface.interfaceNextPage();</script>
```

the method interfaceNextPage() in class JsInterface is:

```
public void interfaceNextPage() {
        Log.i(TAG, "interfaceNextPageBtnReload");
        if ((dataParser != null) && (dataParser.getReplies() != null))
        {
          String str;
          if (!"".equals(dataParser.getReplies()))
            str = dataParser.getReplies();
          else
            str = "0";
          if ((int)Math.ceil(Integer.parseInt(str) / ppp_default_page) <= page)
              webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"nextpagebtnbox\").style.display='none';");
          else
              webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"nextpagebtnbox\").style.display='block';");
        }
    }
```

then, I pre set the webView in onCreage().

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
JsInterface jsInterface = new JsInterface();
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "jsinterface");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

last, I run it, the "next page" is not shown, and from the log, I got some errors:

```
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:278
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:291
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:326
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:339
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:374
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:387
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:422
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if at about:blank:435
E/Web Console(24731): Uncaught TypeError: Object
com.bbk.forumclient.activity.PostListActivity$JsInterface@4054b358 has no method'interfaceNextPage' at about:blank:
```

**please Note:** when I comment the code "webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());"
there is no any worng, and the interfaceNextPage() is not called either, It's so weird. 
and I write this code by this method, from the log, the javascript method can call the java code.
**The question is :** what is wrong with my method to show the "next page". thanks.

Answer (score -2):

There are a few posts floating around suggesting you add

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I'm not sure if this is your problem but it's a quick thing to try.